# Get the dir of $MYVIMRC and concatenate a different file path

Tags: vimrc

Within some run time files I would like to source a file relative to the $MYVIMRC file. My best efforts have lead me to this (which does not work):

```
source expand("$MYVIMRC:p:h") . "/vimrc/env.vim")
```

Comment: source doesn't work for "strings". `:exe "source " . expand("$MYVIMRC:p:h") . "/vimrc/env.vim"` might work, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best effort:

```
source expand("$MYVIMRC:p:h") . "/vimrc/env.vim")
```

has issues:

1. `source` command doesn't work with `"strings"`
2. even if it worked with strings, you have strange last unbalanced `)`

You can try using `:execute` statement with composed `source`:

```
:exe "source " . fnamemodify("$MYVIMRC", ":p:h") . "/vimrc/env.vim"
```

Note that `expand("$MYVIMRC:p:h")` will not work as expected, but `fnamemodify` will.

Another option I personally use is:

```
source <sfile>:h/statusline.vim
```

where `<sfile>` when executing a ":source" command, is replaced with the file name of the sourced file.

Comment: expand("$MYVIMRC:p:h") result in a path ending with the literal ":p:h", so ":exe "source " . expand("$MYVIMRC:p:h") . "/vimrc/env.vim"" does not work

Comment: @run_the_race indeed. `fnamemodify` would fix this

Comment: I had to do `fnamemodify(expand("$MYVIMRC"), ":p:h") to get this to work ... or fnamemodify($MYVIMRC, ":p:h") `

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
execute printf('source %s/vimrc/env.vim', fnamemodify($MYVIMRC, ':h'))
```